# Template url with Django class-based view

Tags: django, url, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I'm working with class-based views in Django, and I've made a simple view in which I show all the posts of the blog

```
class PostList(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_list.html"
```

Now I need to put a link that redirects to the homepage (that is PostList). I worked with function-based views before; the function was

```
def post_list(request):
    #code
```

and the link in the template was

```
<a href="{% url 'blog.views.post_list' %}">Homepage</a>
```

I tried to put "PostList" instead of "post_list", but I'm clearly missing something here.
How could I do that?

EDIT:

This is urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.PostList.as_view()),
    #other urls
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

EDIT 2:

Got it. Here's what I had to do:

Give the urlpattern a "name"

```
url(r'^$', views.PostList.as_view(), name="post_list")
```

And then change the template tag

```
<a href="{% url 'post_list' %}">Pin a Voyage</a>
```

Comment: The tag takes the name of the url pattern, which you set in urls.py. Please show that file.

Comment: Added to the post.

Comment: Got it. I made it work, I'm writing down the solution.